# Hovering over the image undesirably changes the background of the entire container, not just the image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, footer

When I hover over the image, the entire color of the container it's in, including the footer, changes, which I don't want. I only want the color of the image to change, but not the footer. I think it's because the footer is in the child element of the entire container in which the image is located, but if I took it out, the position of the footer would no longer align with the position of the image, which I don't want. What can I do to solve the problem?

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar"><a href="/" class="nav-branding">TEST</a>
                <ul class="nav-menu">
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="/">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="/">IMPRESSUM</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="picture-container">
        <div class="picture"><img class="bau-picture" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5288770/pexels-photo-5288770.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" alt="Bild ist nicht verfügbar">
            <div class="footer">
                <h5>GER&Uuml;STBAU</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="picture"><img class="bau-picture" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8853507/pexels-photo-8853507.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" alt="Bild ist nicht verfügbar">
            <div class="footer">BAU</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
/* Allgemeine Stile */
 * {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     font-family: "Anta", sans-serif;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-style: normal;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Body-Stile */
 body {
     position: relative;
}
/* Header-Stile */
 header {
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     padding-left: 2%;
    /* Linker äußerer Abstand */
     padding-right: 2%;
    /* Rechter äußerer Abstand */
}
/* Listen-Stile */
 li {
     list-style: none;
}
/* Link-Stile */
 a {
     text-decoration: none;
}
/* Navbar-Stile */
 .navbar, .navbar a {
     color: black;
}
/* Markenlogo-Stile */
 .nav-branding {
     font-size: 1.875rem;
}
/* Navbar-Stile */
 .navbar{
     width: 95%;
     margin: auto;
     min-height: 70px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
}
/* Menü-Stile */
 .nav-menu{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     gap: 3.75rem;
}
/* Bildcontainer-Stile */
 #picture-container {
     margin: auto;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     margin-left: 2%;
    /* Linker äußerer Abstand */
     margin-right: 2%;
    /* Rechter äußerer Abstand */
    /* padding-right: 2%;
    */
}
/* Container-Stile */
 .container {
     width: 100%;
     margin: auto;
}
/* Bild-Stile */
 .picture {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     flex: 1;
     border: 1px solid;
     margin-right: 2%;
     margin-left: 2%;
}
/* Erster Fußbereich-Stile */
 .footer:first-child {
     border-top: none;
}
/* Fußbereich-Stile */
 .footer {
     border-top: 1px solid;
     padding: 5px;
     height: 8vh;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     text-align: left;
     font-size: 4vh;
}
/* Media-Query-Stile */
 .picture img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
}
 .picture:hover {
     background: yellow;
}
/* Media Queries für Bildcontainer bei maximaler Breite von 1280px */
 @media(max-width: 1280px) {
     .picture-container {
         width: calc(100% - 2 * 5%);
         margin-left: 5%;
         margin-right: 5%;
    }
}
/* Media Queries für Bildcontainer bei mindestens 1024px Breite */
 @media(min-width: 1024px) {
     #picture-container {
         height: 90vh;
    }
}
/* Media Queries für Bildcontainer bei maximaler Breite von 768px */
 @media(max-width: 768px) {
     #picture-container {
         flex-direction: column;
         margin: 0;
    }
     .picture {
         border-right: 1px solid;
        /* Damit die Footer an seinem rechten Rand immer noch eine Trennlinie haben, wenn sie vertikal angeordnet werden*/
         margin: 0;
    }
}
```

I've already tried accessing just the image. I also tried setting the footer color to none, but to no avail.

Comment: _"I only want the color of the image to change"_ - and what exactly is that supposed to _mean_ here in this situation? Your images are both JPEGs - so they can't have any alpha transparency, but are completely "solid". So where exactly would you expect to _see_ a change of the background color assigned to those images ...?

Comment: You have a container around _both_ pictures... what if you also have a container around each _individual_ picture, and the footers are children of that inner container rather than the picture? Since each picture and its footer are in the same inner container as each other, they should line up?

Comment: @CBroe when you visit the website https://www.desa.studio/ you will se what I mean when you hover over the pictures. I can not really explain it with my words.

Comment: @NickGris I do not understand what you mean

Comment: _"when you visit the website desa.studio you will se what I mean when you hover over the pictures."_ - that effect appears to be based on changing the `opacity` on hover, so that a background color can "blend through."

Comment: As cBroe said your images are JPEG not png  so dont have transparancy and .footer is a child so that is normal behavior. For not to change child background you Can use .picuture:not(.footer) :hover{background :yellow;}

Comment: Your .picture-container is flex so childs are flex and takes the available space. Your .picture-container background dont change.

Comment: @Sami-CanDurademir: Currently you have `Container (Picture (Footer) ) (Picture (Footer) )` where brackets means 'nested inside'. I'm suggesting this: `Container (Inner Container (Picture) (Footer) ) (Inner Container (Picture) (Footer) )` - the footers are now outside the picture divs, and each picture + its footer is in its own inner container div (which should keep them the same width). Any better?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the easiest to just add the background to the `.footer`. And you'll need to add the opacity to an image, as @CBroe mentioned.

```css
/* Allgemeine Stile */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Anta", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Body-Stile */

body {
  position: relative;
}


/* Header-Stile */

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  /* Linker äußerer Abstand */
  padding-right: 2%;
  /* Rechter äußerer Abstand */
}


/* Listen-Stile */

li {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Link-Stile */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Navbar-Stile */

.navbar,
.navbar a {
  color: black;
}


/* Markenlogo-Stile */

.nav-branding {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
}


/* Navbar-Stile */

.navbar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Menü-Stile */

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 3.75rem;
}


/* Bildcontainer-Stile */

#picture-container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 2%;
  /* Linker äußerer Abstand */
  margin-right: 2%;
  /* Rechter äußerer Abstand */
  /* padding-right: 2%;
    */
}


/* Container-Stile */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Bild-Stile */

.picture {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}


/* Erster Fußbereich-Stile */

.footer:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}


/* Fußbereich-Stile */

.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 8vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 4vh;
  background: #fff;
}


/* Media-Query-Stile */

.picture img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.picture:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

.picture:hover img {
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/* Media Queries für Bildcontainer bei maximaler Breite von 1280px */

@media(max-width: 1280px) {
  .picture-container {
    width: calc(100% - 2 * 5%);
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  }
}


/* Media Queries für Bildcontainer bei mindestens 1024px Breite */

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
  #picture-container {
    height: 90vh;
  }
}


/* Media Queries für Bildcontainer bei maximaler Breite von 768px */

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  #picture-container {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .picture {
    border-right: 1px solid;
    /* Damit die Footer an seinem rechten Rand immer noch eine Trennlinie haben, wenn sie vertikal angeordnet werden*/
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar"><a href="/" class="nav-branding">TEST</a>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="/">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="/">IMPRESSUM</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="picture-container">
  <div class="picture">
    <img class="bau-picture" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5288770/pexels-photo-5288770.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" alt="Bild ist nicht verfügbar">
    <div class="footer">
      <h5>GER&Uuml;STBAU</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="picture">
    <img class="bau-picture" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8853507/pexels-photo-8853507.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" alt="Bild ist nicht verfügbar">
    <div class="footer">BAU</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might want to add the wrapper tag for an image to avoid specifying footer background but it would require layout changes.